# How to calculate Time Difference Average?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following data in my database.

```
EmployeeId    ServiceStart  ServiceEnd     EstimateSErviceTime  ServiceSuccess
1             1:00          2:30           1:00                 ?%
2             2:00          3:00           00:45
3             3:00          3:30           00:30
4             12:00         1:30           1:15
5             2:00          3:00           1:30
```

I want to calculate service Success for employee like this

var serviceSuccess = count of interactions in reason where (ServiceTime(ServiceEnd-ServiceStart) <= EstimateServiceTime) / interactionCount

I am trying to do it like this:

```
SUM(case when AverageServiceTime < EstimateServiceTime then 1
         else 0
    end) / COUNT(I.Id)  ServiceSuccess
from Interaction I
```

How to calculate ServiceSucess.

Comment: why does row 3 (EmployeeId 3 ) go back in time? is that a typo?

Comment: @Tanner yes, it was typo, fixed.

Comment: can you show the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close.  One problem is integer division, which will tend to result in `0` all the time.

I would just do this as:

```
select avg(case when AverageServiceTime < EstimateServiceTime then 1.0 else 0 end) as  ServiceSuccess
from Interaction I
```